# Sharing a 1 GB HD file that can be stream more then 10 computer simultinuasly

Tags: networking

I want to share a file that is sized at 1 GB and my OS is Linux Ubuntu 12.10 via a wireless router by the name of TP-link with a speed of around 400MBps. I want to share this file to at least 10 computers that are capable to "play" the file simultaneously at the same time.

Can anyone help me to share this file? Thus far I've tried to share it via Samba and also Apache2 but I can't stream or play to more than two or three computers at the same time.

Comment: I don't really think you can do this over wireless.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to stream the data at a constant rate, or to copy it? If you're streaming, are all the clients reading the same part at the same time? If the answers are “stream” and “no”, you're probably limited by the available bandwidth.

Comment: Dear Gilles   :     i have 1GB file i want to share this file over a wireless network that is capable to play the file simultinuasly in ten computer at the same time . just wanting to play the file which is shared

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is probably multicast/broadast using a video stream brodcasting player such as VLC Media Player.

It will allow you (through a wizard or manually) to stream any input source to your local network using either UDP multicast (which requires to setup IPv4 Multicast Groups) or HTTP streaming.

This tutorial should help you : [VideoLAN Streaming Howto](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/).

Comment: First: Do not name your links *this* or *here*. Give it a meaningful name like “VLC - Streaming howto”. Second: Do not only paste a link, but sum up the information. In case the link dies, your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this tutorial using VLC which might give you what you want. The tutorial is titled: [How To: Play Music/Video Simultaneously on Multiple Computers](http://www.overclock.net/t/378530/how-to-play-music-video-simultaneously-on-multiple-computers).

#### General steps

Assuming you have VLC installed on the server and the client computers.

On the computer serving the stream:

1. Click File, then Wizard. Select Stream to Network, then click next.
2. On the input screen you can either use what is currently in the playlist or a saved file. You can select music files, video files, discs, or even playlists. I chose to use a playlist.

   [image: ss of stream to network dialog]
3. On the streaming screen select RTP Multicast. Next fill in the address you will be using. For example, 239.255.100.100. Then click next.

   [image: ss of streaming dialog]
4. Go through the rest of the wizard using the default selections.
5. Now connect to the stream using a client instance of VLC. In VLC: click File, Open Network Stream, and then choose UDP/RTP Multicast. Enter the address from step #3 (239.255.100.100) and leave the port numbers alone. Click OK and then you should hear/see the music/video being played (may take a few seconds). Do this step for each computer that wants to watch/listen.